# Get button text with BeautifulSoup Python or Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the Website url and Whitepaper url from the page https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bob/ in the left column.

[image]

I'm using BeautifulSoup `soup.findAll(string='Whitepaper')` and similar but the page seems changing structure everytime. The following attempt worked fine but now it doesn't:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from soup2dict import convert
import requests

url='https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bob/'

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

tag=soup.find_all(class_="link-button", recursive=True)
for t in tag:
    if 'Whitepaper' in str(t):
        tt=convert(t)
        print(tt['@href'])
```

I'm also using Selenium to interact with other parts of the website, so a solution with Selenium Python is good as well.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below using selenium

```
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ExpectedConditions
from selenium import webdriver
url = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bob/'
driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path=EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install())
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get(url)
websiteButton = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[text()="Website"]')
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(websiteButton).perform()
urlElement = wait.until(
    ExpectedConditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class="tippy-content"] span')))
print(urlElement.text)
```

Prints

```
www.zkbob.com
```

Comment: Thank you, but it seems the website changed. When opened with webdriver the button "Website" shows the url directly

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Abhay Chaudhary, for the whitepaper you can use

```
whitepaperButton = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//a[text()="Whitepaper"]')
print(whitepaperButton.get_attribute('href'))
```